# Maximum sum of absolute differences dynamic programming

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

We have an array of `N` elements. I have to choose `K` elements from this array(you can't take an element with index that is greater than the index of the element of the next one) in such a way that the sum `abs(a1-a0)+abs(a2-a1)+...+(ak-ak-1)` is maximized. My idea is 2d DP and goes like this: The solution that involves taking the `n`-th element while having taken `k` elements is the maximum of the solutions where element with index `j` smaller than `i` is the last one, `j` 
 from `k-1`, `j<i` plus taking the `abs(numbers[n]-numbers[j])`. Here is my code. Where is my mistake?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class SumOfAbsoluteDifferences {

    static int solve(int numbers[], int N, int K) {
        int[][] dp = new int[N][K];
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<K; j++)
                dp[i][j] = 0;
        }

        int E = 1;

        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int maxx = -99999;

            for (int j=E-1; j<i; j++) {

                    if (dp[j][E-1] + Math.abs(numbers[i] - numbers[j]) > maxx) {
                        maxx = dp[j][E-1] + Math.abs(numbers[i] - numbers[j]);
                    }

            }
            if(E < K && E-1>=0) {
                dp[i][E-1] = maxx;
                E++;
            }

        }

        int maks = -9999;
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            if (dp[i][K-1] > maks)
                maks = dp[i][K-1];
        }
        return maks;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int i,j,k;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
        int N = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        int K = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

        int numbers[] = new int[N];

        st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
        for (i=0;i<N;i++) {
            numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        }

        int res = solve(numbers, N, K);
        System.out.println(res);

        br.close();

    }

}
```

For example this test case:

> 10 3 1 9 2 3 6 1 3 2 1 3

My code gives 0, it should be 16.

Comment: "Where is my mistake": provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise it's hard to help. Or instead, read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and find the bug yourself.

Comment: what is the value of k in you test case